# Pass a URL into a Dart app

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have a page with links. These links all end in the same way. For example `www.site.com/fruit/apples, www.site.com/fruit/bananas, www.site.com/fruit/oranges`, etc. I want all these links to call the same Dart app and have the app do some processing and then redirect you wherever you need to go (the bananas page vs. the oranges page). This way, I avoid having an actual HTML file for every single fruit. I can instead have a single landing template that gets populated with variable fruit data.

The part I'm hung up on is passing the url into the Dart app so it can do the handling. I understand `main()` cannot receive arguments, so what's another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [route package](https://github.com/dart-lang/route) to handle the URL's for you.

For example:

```dart
import 'package:route/client.dart';

final fruitUrl = new UrlPattern(r'/fruit/(\w+)');

main() {
  var router = new Router()
    ..addHandler(fruitUrl, showFruit)
    ..listen();
}

void showFruit(String path) {
  var fruit = fruitUrl.parse(req.path)[0];
  // Display the page according to the fruit type
}
```

If you don't need to handle actual routes, and you just want to handle any query parameters passed of the form `?fruit=apple` you don't have to use the routes package and can instead manually parse the URL:

```dart
Map params = {};

// If arguments were provided, decode them into params map
if(window.location.search.length > 1) {
  // Break all arguments into form: fruit=apple
  List<String> queryPairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
  for(String queryPair in queryPairs) {
    // Add arguments into params map: key=fruit, value=apple
    List<String> queryPairList = queryPair.split('=');
    params[queryPairList[0]] = queryPairList[1];
  }
}

// Handle the proper action based on the fruit
switch(params['fruit']) {
  case 'apple':
    // ...
    break;
    // ...
  case 'orange':
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting `Breaking on exception: Illegal argument(s): No handler found for /web/out/entry_page.html`. I'm testing in the Dart editor and also on a web server. Same error.

Comment: The code I provided will only handle URL's starting with /fruit. You'll have to add another handler to handle entry_page.html (add a new UrlPattern, a method to handle it, and then the router handler that will bind them). Also, stick with the web server only when testing routes, as there is an issue with Dart Editor that will prevent it from working properly (Dart Editor serves files from the local filesystem path which won't match the specified route).

Comment: What I'm really and truly after is a way to parse a ?fruit= style query. I should have made that clear before, but I think the logic is the same, but the regex is different. I can't escape that exception, though. I've noticed that when I do a "deploy", the route package does not show up in the deploy/out folder. Dunno if that's got anything to do with this.

Comment: In that case there's no need to use the routes package. You can manually parse URL parameters. I've updated my answer.